# horizontal float item pushed down in chrome, but not firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

Why is the last list item in the submenu lower than the rest in Chrome, but aligned in Firefox?

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/airwwwave/zjckk9uL/3/) with font turned red for visibility

[ACTUAL SITE](http://airwwwave.com/inter/sky-energy/index.html)

I have tried everything I can think of with padding, margin, vertical align, last child, etc. Baffled. Thank you.

```
#hmenuWrapper {
    width: 100%;
}

#hmenu, #hmenu ul, #hmenu ul li, #hmenu ul li a {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 1;
    font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
}

#hmenu:before, #hmenu:after, #hmenu > ul:before, #hmenu > ul:after {
    content: '';
    display: table;
}

#hmenu:after, #cssmenu > ul:after {
    clear: both;
}

#hmenu {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 180px;
    zoom: 1;
    height: 60px;
    width: 740px;
    background: url(../media/images/bottom-bg.png) repeat-x center bottom;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

#hmenu ul {
    background: url(../media/images/nav-bg.png) repeat-x 0px 4px;
    height: 69px;
}

#hmenu ul li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
}

#hmenu ul li a {
    display: block;
    height: 37px;
    padding: 17px 14px 0;
    margin: 4px 0px 0;
    border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
    font-weight: 400;
    opacity: .9;
}

#hmenu ul li:first-child a {
    margin: 4px 0px 0 0;
}

#hmenu ul li:last-child {
    background-color: #168b09;
}

#hmenu ul li a:hover {
    background: url(../media/images/colorHover.png) center bottom;
    display: block;
    height: 37px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    color: #616161;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .35);
    opacity: 1;
}

#hmenu ul li.active a {
    background: url(../media/images/color.png) center bottom;
    display: block;
    height: 37px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    color: #616161;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .35);
    opacity: 1;
}



#nav-wrap {
    position: relative;
    left: 180px;
    top: -3px;
    zoom: 1;
    height: 40px;
    width: 740px;
    float: left;
    background: url(../media/images/colorinv.png);
}

#nav {
    display: inline;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
}

#nav a:hover {
    color: #444444;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#nav li:hover {
    background: url(../media/images/nav-bginvHover.png);
}

    #nav a li:hover  {
        color: #444444;
    }


#nav ui li a {
    height: 40px;
    width: 185px;
}

.nav-item {
    float: left;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 185px;
    list-style-type: none;
    color: white;
}

.nav-item a {
    height: 40px;
    width: 185px;
}

#nav li.nav-sel {
    float: left;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 185px;
    list-style-type: none;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
    background: url(../media/images/nav-bginv.png);
}

#nav li.nav-sel a {
    color: white;
    height: 40px;
    width: 185px;
    line-height: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `display: inline` from `#nav`, it's not needed: https://jsfiddle.net/ry5mLkaL/1/

Also, your HTML is invalid starting at line 42. You should not wrap a List Item with an Anchor (or anything). The anchor should be inside of the List Item.

```
 <ul id="nav">
    <a href="pages/companyServices.html"><li class="nav-item">Company Services</li></a>
    <a href="pages/skyAdvantages.html"><li class="nav-item">Sky Advantages</li></a>
    <a href="pages/customerRecognition.html"><li class="nav-item">Customer Recognition</li></a>
    <a href="pages/newsReleases.html"><li class="nav-item">News Releases</li></a>
 </ul>
```

to

```
<ul id="nav">
     <li class="nav-item"><a href="pages/companyServices.html">Company Services</a></li>
     <li class="nav-item"><a href="pages/skyAdvantages.html">Sky Advantages</a></li>
     <li class="nav-item"><a href="pages/customerRecognition.html">Customer Recognition</a></li>
     <li class="nav-item"><a href="pages/newsReleases.html">News Releases</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you all. All of these worked. @Shane also gave me the bonus of finding my HTML goof. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Because of #nav `display:inline`.
Set it to `display:table-row;`

Answer (score 0):

Add `#nav{padding-left: 0px}` to your CSS, see fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zjckk9uL/4/